# Scrapy - last result only

Tags: python, scrapy

I have almost got this scrapy program down, except for this last problem. I am attempting to

1. iterate over a list on each of several entries on a page
2. extract a piece of data on this first list page for each entry ['RStation']
3. enter each of the entries' urls via its href
4. extract some data by iterating over a list on this next page
5. create a single item with data from main page and following page

The problem is that when I open my csv, I am only see duplicates of the last entry on the 2nd iterated list (for each entry of the first list).

Am I appending the items incorrectly or misapplying response.meta in some way? I tried to follow the documentation for response.meta and I can't understand why this is not working.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from fspeople.items import FspeopleItem

class FSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "fspeople"
allowed_domains = ["fs.fed.us"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?3employeename=&keywords=&station_id=SRS&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=RMRS&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=PSW&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=PNW&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=NRS&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=IITF&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=FPL&state_id=ALL",
    #"http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=WO&state_id=ALL"
]
def __init__(self):
    self.i = 0

def parse(self,response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//a[@title='Click to view their profile ...']/@href"):
        item = FspeopleItem()
        url = response.urljoin(sel.extract())
        item['RStation'] = response.xpath("//table[@id='table_id']/tbody/tr/td[2]/i/b/text() | //table[@id='table_id']/tbody/td[2]/text()").extract_first().strip()
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_post)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
    self.i += 1

def parse_post(self, response):
    theitems = []
    pubs = response.xpath("//div/h2[text()='Featured Publications & Products']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li | //div/h2[text()='Publications']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li")
    for i in pubs:
        item = response.meta['item']
        name = response.xpath("//div[@id='maincol']/h1/text() | //nobr/text()").extract_first().strip()
        pubname = i.xpath("a/text()").extract_first().strip()
        pubauth = i.xpath("text()").extract_first().strip()
        pubURL = i.xpath("a/@href").extract_first().strip()
        #RStation = response.xpath("//div[@id='right-float']/div/div/ul/li/a/text()").extract_first().strip()

        item['link'] = response.url
        item['name'] = name
        item['pubname'] = pubname
        item['pubauth'] = pubauth
        item['pubURL'] = pubURL
        #item['RStation'] = RStation

        theitems.append(item)
    return theitems
```

Comment: You are overriding `__init__` but you're not calling super for scrapy.Spider

Comment: You're iterating on the same item in your loop. Try `item = response.meta.get ('item')

Answer (score 0):

create a new instance of item for each iteration.

```
def parse_post(self, response):
    [...]
    for i in pubs:
        item = response.meta['item']
        item = item.copy()
        [...]
```